# increment colnames of a data.frame by 1

Tags: regex, r, string, dataframe, increment

Having a data.frame with colnames

```
nam <- c("a", paste0("a_", seq(12)))
"a" "a_1" "a_2" "a_3" "a_4" "a_5" "a_6" "a_7" "a_8" "a_9" "a_10" "a_11" "a_12"
```

How can i increment the numbers of the names with numbers by 1?

The expected Result would be

```
"a" "a_2" "a_3" "a_4" "a_5" "a_6" "a_7" "a_8" "a_9" "a_10" "a_11" "a_12" "a_13"
```

So far my solution looks very complicated... Is there an easier way than

```
increment_names <- function(nam){
  where <- regexpr("\\d", nam)
  ind <- which(where > 0)
  increment <- as.numeric(substring(nam[ind], where[ind])) + 1
  substring(nam[ind], where[ind]) <- as.character(increment)
  nam
}

> increment_names(nam)
 [1] "a" "a_2" "a_3" "a_4" "a_5" "a_6" "a_7" "a_8" "a_9" "a_10" "a_11" "a_12" "a_13"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base `regmatches` solution:

```
r <- regexpr("\\d+", nam)
regmatches(nam, r) <- as.numeric(regmatches(nam, r)) + 1
nam
# [1] "a"    "a_2"  "a_3"  "a_4"  "a_5"  "a_6"  "a_7"  "a_8"  ...
```

Comment: Awesome, would have never thought to use the replacement form of this.

Answer (score 5):

with `gsubfn` package you could do something simple as

```
library(gsubfn) 
gsubfn("\\d+", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1, nam)
## [1] "a"    "a_2"  "a_3"  "a_4"  "a_5"  "a_6"  "a_7"  "a_8"  "a_9"  "a_10" "a_11" "a_12" "a_13"
```

This will work for *any* pattern and you don't need to assume the  "*nonnumbers_numbers*" pattern mentioned above, for example

```
(nam <- c("a", paste0(seq(12), "_a")))
## [1] "a"    "1_a"  "2_a"  "3_a"  "4_a"  "5_a"  "6_a"  "7_a"  "8_a"  "9_a"  "10_a" "11_a" "12_a"
gsubfn("\\d+", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1, nam)
## [1] "a"    "2_a"  "3_a"  "4_a"  "5_a"  "6_a"  "7_a"  "8_a"  "9_a"  "10_a" "11_a" "12_a" "13_a"
```

Comment: (+1) for no need of the "nonnumbers_numbers" pattern.
As i have this pattern i go with the _base_ solution

Comment: interesting `gsubfn` converts NAs to "" instead of "NA" `as.character`.  +1 for reminding me of `gsubfn`.

Comment: @BrodieG, just FYI, I was in a middle of posting the exact same solution like you did, but then saw your edits and realised we are going to post the same thing, so thanks to that I came up with this gem alternatively :)

Comment: You already have my vote on this from a few days ago, but I thought you might be interested in a package that I recently came across that has similar functionality to what you've done here, but is *way* faster. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28038269/1270695).

Comment: @AnandaMahto interesting (+1) did you benchmark it? Do you know what causes it be more efficient?

Answer (score 4):

This does it so long as your pattern is "nonnumbers_numbers":

```
nums <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", nam))
nam[!is.na(nums)] <- paste0(gsub("[0-9]", "", nam), nums + 1)[!is.na(nums)]
```

Produces:

```
 [1] "a"    "a_2"  "a_3"  "a_4"  "a_5"  "a_6"  "a_7"  "a_8"  "a_9"  "a_10" "a_11" "a_12"
 [13] "a_13"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the "ore" package, with which your substitutions can be functions, like this:

```
nam <- c("a", paste0("a_", seq(12)))
nam
library(ore)
ore.subst("-?\\d+", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1, nam, all = TRUE)
#  [1] "a"    "a_2"  "a_3"  "a_4"  "a_5"  "a_6"  "a_7"  "a_8"  "a_9" 
# [10] "a_10" "a_11" "a_12" "a_13"
```

---

This is similar functionality to the "gsubfn" package, but (in this case at least) is a lot more efficient. Here are some benchmarks:

```
library(stringi)
set.seed(1)
nam <- stri_rand_strings(10000, 5, pattern = "[A-J0-9]")

f_ORE <- function(invec = nam) {
  ore.subst("-?\\d+", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1, invec, all = TRUE)
} 

f_GSUBFN <- function(invec = nam) {
  gsubfn("\\d+", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1, invec)
}

f_BASE <- function(invec = nam) {
  r <- regexpr("\\d+", invec)
  regmatches(invec, r) <- as.numeric(regmatches(invec, r))+1
  invec
}

system.time(f_GSUBFN())
#    user  system elapsed 
#    5.48    0.01    5.50 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f_BASE(), f_ORE())
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#  f_BASE() 141.79743 149.58914 161.49041 152.81038 162.10550 357.6483   100
#   f_ORE()  57.35309  59.58433  65.84678  60.92218  68.40062 116.7714   100
```

Note that while the "ore" approach and "gsubfn" approach area identical, they seem to be a little different from the base R approach.

Consider:

```
> identical(f_ORE(), f_GSUBFN())
[1] TRUE

## Edge case...
> nam[988]
[1] "0G019"
> f_ORE()[988]     ## 019 becomes 20 (without the leading zero)
[1] "1G20"
> f_GSUBFN()[988]  ## Same
[1] "1G20"
> f_BASE()[988]    ## This seems off...
[1] "1G019"
```